# Sound crackles in one speaker same way quality worsens with volume, but not with front headphones output

Tags: sound, 18.04, pulseaudio, alsa

I have a new PC with [ASUS ROG STRIX X299-E GAMING](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/ROG-STRIX-X299-E-GAMING/) motherboard and I've installed latest ubuntu on it

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

$ uname -a
Linux fprochazka-beast 4.15.0-23-generic #25-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 23 18:02:16 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And the sound is really bad. It crackles like when you enable "over amplification" in sound settings and max it out.

I've googled a bit and found some hints that `alsamixer` might show something and it did. This is how the settings looks when I start the computer

[image: alsamixer default]

When I lower the PCM it gets better but the volume lowers which I don't really like

[image: alsamixer lower]

I've also tried [disabling `tsched`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#Glitches.2C_skips_or_crackling) but that did nothing

How can I please help Ubuntu (and alsa and pulseaudio) to set sensible defaults so the sound quality is good?

---

update: I've realized that the problem is only with the right speaker (I have 2.1 speakers), the left one works perfectly.

---

update: When I connect the speakers using front headphones output, they work perfectly.